# xtext implement custom IResourceValidator

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I have xtext language which has an external compiler for context checking. I would like show the errors from the compiler in the editor. I’ve read somewhere that I have to implement a IResourceValidator. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use bindIResourceValidator() to bind your own implementation.

For example, like this:

```
public Class<? extends IResourceValidator> bindIResourceValidator() {
 return MyValidator.class;
 }
```

Keep in mind, you'll use the original validator provided by Xtext